# Python string, find specific word, then copy the word after it

Tags: python, string, parsing

I'm having a problem doing such operation, say we have a string

```
teststring = "This is a test of number, number: 525, number: 585, number2: 559"
```

I want to store 525 and 585 into a list, how can I do this?

I did it in a very stupid way, works but there must be better ways

```
teststring = teststring.split()
found = False
    for word in teststring:
        if found:
            templist.append(word)
            found = False
        if word is "number:":
            found = True
```

Are there solutions with regex?

Followup: What if I want to store 525, 585 and 559?

Comment: Why do you want to use a regex here? A plain list comprehension will be quicker and actually readable

Comment: @tobyodavies would you need to a few steps like split and parse numbers etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`re`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) module:

```
>>> re.findall(r'number\d*: (\d+)',teststring)
['525', '585', '559']
```

`\d` is any digit [0-9]
`*` means from 0 to infinity times
`()` denotes what to capture
`+` means from 1 to infinity times

If you need to convert generated strings to `int`s, use [`map`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map):

```
>>> map(int, ['525', '585', '559'])
[525, 585, 559]
```

or

[list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> [int(s) for s in ['525', '585', '559']]
[525, 585, 559]
```

Comment: Hi ovgolovin, thank you for the answer. Very clear. the \d+ would mean it would capture any amount of digits, correct?

Comment: @Guagua Yes, `+` means from 1 to infinity. If you need exactly 3, use `{3}` instead of `+`.

Comment: i know this is a dumb question, re.findall(r'
what is that r for?

Comment: @Guagua See the second and third paragraphs at the very top of this article http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html about what `raw string`s are and why they are needed.

Comment: yes yes, i read it a while ago and forgot about it..very helpful, thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use regex groups to accomplish this. Here's some sample code:

```
import re
teststring = "This is a test of number, number: 525, number: 585, number2: 559"
groups = re.findall(r"number2?: (\d{3})", teststring)
```

`groups` then contains the numbers. This syntax uses regex groups.

Comment: But only 525 and 585 are wanted.

Comment: thanks Vacation, could you please explain
findall(r"number2?: (\d{3})"

Comment: @Guagua `number` is self explanatory, `2?` matches zero or one occurrences of `2`, the colon and space match a colon and a space, `(\d{3})` matches and captures three digits.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
import re
[int(x) for x in re.findall(r' \d+', teststring)]
```

which will give you:

```
[525, 585, 559]
```

Comment: This only answers half of the question

Comment: Unless he searches all the 3 digits followed by a comma wich answers also the initial question.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest:

```
teststring = "This is a test of number, number: 525, number: 585, number2: 559"
# The following does: "This is a test of number, number: 525, number: 585, number2: 559" -> ["525, number", "585, number2", "559"]
a = teststring.split(': ')[1:]
# The following does: ["525, number", "585, number2", "559"] -> ["525", " number", "585", " number2", "559"]
b = [i.split(',') for i in a]
# The following does: [["525", " number"], ["585", " number2"], ["559"]] -> ["525", "585", "559"]
c = [i[0] for i in b]
>>> c
['525', '585', '559']
```

Comment: what does this do? [1:]

Comment: @Guagua If: a = [a, b, c, d]; a[1:] = [b, c, d]

Answer (score 0):

It's not the most efficient code in the world, but it is still probably better than a regex:

```
tokens = teststring.split()
numlist = [val for key, val in zip(tokens, tokens[1:]) if key == 'number:']
```

for your follow-up and more general queries:

```
def find_next_tokens(teststring, test):
    tokens = teststring.split()
    return [val for key, val in zip(tokens, tokens[1:]) if test(key)]
```

Which could be called as:

```
find_next_tokens(teststring, lambda s: s.startswith('number') and s.endswith(':'))
```

This will help if the keys to search for come from user input:

```
find_next_tokens(teststring, lambda s: s in valid_keys)
```

Comment: could you please explain why the solution is better than regex? efficiency or something else?

Comment: Regexes are hard to debug, if you don't need one I'd recommend against using one. I find this a lot easier to tell what is happening and it's not any more code than a regex + interpreting the match data. Good luck if you ever want to get a list of keys from the user and parse that with a regex.